# Memory leak in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks

We are using pushlet in our project(to update values from server to client side), in that we have a code as following-->

```
out.println("<script language=JavaScript id='testScript' >"+"var jso = `"+ttmp+";parent.setTest(jso);"+"</script>");`
//where ttmp has some datas to update the iframe value.
```

We are using this script to update a table in a iframe, after updating we are deleting this script using the following code,

```
function setTest(jso) {
..process jso
var testNode = document.push.document.getElementById('testScript');
testNode.innerHtml="";
testNode.parentNode.removeChild(statNode);
//delete testNode;
testNode = null;
}
```

After deleting or removing child, memory is not released in IE 6.0. we find constant increase in memory by 4KB after 8 minutes.

Any suggestions???????

- We tried in IE 6.0 & 7.0

Comment: You mean, it keeps increasing and **never** comes down?  Whatever I remember of IE jscript engine is : the garabage collection is not predictable.

Comment: after 8 minutes, its continuously increasing each time by 4KB...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The node is probably not what is using memory, but rather the changes you do elsewhere based on the data initialized data in the node. that data is still present after you remove the node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We tried to empty the innerHTML by testNode.innerHTML = "" won't it clear the data in the node.

Comment: Yes but since the node has instantiated javascript variables and since your code makes other changes, chances are that the memory is not really used by the node itself, but rather as the consequences of the node. thus removing the node doesn't help. For instance if you load 10MB of data into a js variable through a script tag and then remove the script tag, the 10MB still exists in the javascript variable.

Comment: Ok, if you are familiar with other any way to do that? Kindly let me know it will be useful for me....:)

Comment: set variables that holds large chunks of data to `null` when you no longer need them or better yet make sure they live in a  limited scope so they will automatically get garbage collected with the scope.

Comment: we have tried for null and they are in the limited function scope(i.e. inside the function). We have also tried it by declaring it with keyword var and without it but, after some period of time the memory keeps on increasing by 4KB and never stops. When does that increase in memory will stop or will it actually stop???

Answer (score 0):

Are you detaching the scripts you are pushing from the server apart from clearing the nodes ?

Comment: pass some common name  into script id attribute, once the task is done try to delete by fetching elements with document.getElementsByTagName("script") and delete obtained elements by validating against the common name

Comment: We are doing the same approach var testNode = document.push.document.getElementById('testScript');
testNode.innerHtml="";
testNode.parentNode.removeChild(testNode);